# Rate of change question Calculus

Tags: calculus

David and Clara have made cookie dough for the senior bakesale. They have made
C(t)= 1/5 t(t+5)(t+3)(t+1) cookies after t hours. At which rate are they making cookies after 2 hours?

Do I just plug in 2 into the equation? I am confused and need a few steps to help me.

Comment: Do you how to find the "rate of change" of a function?

Comment: if you plug in 2, all you're going to get is the _amount_ of cookies made after 2 hours... to find the _rate_, you take the first derivative, and then plug in 2

Answer (score 0):

You need to take the derivative first to ascertain the rate of change, the put in $t=2$ to get the rate of change at that time.